# Firebase reference call not returning proper object (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple messaging app and the below function is being called and being passed the uid of the person who sent the message. The proper uid is being sent everytime the function is called, but the user is not the user related to that uid. Instead, it is returning the first user the number of times that person has messages and then returning the next user the number of times that person has messages.

For example, if I have two users in a chat (Sue and Bob) and Sue has 10 messages total in this chat and Bob has 7, it returns Sue as the user for the first 10 messages and then Bob as the user for the final 7.

```
private func fetchUser(withId uid: String) {

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageURL"] as? String
            self.users.append(user)
            self.attemptReloadOfCollection()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Called From:

```
private func observeMessages() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }

    let groupId = groupIdFromPreviousController

    let groupMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("groups").child(groupId).child("messages")
    groupMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let messageId = snapshot.key

        let messagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("all-messages").child(messageId)
        messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let message = Message(dictionary: dictionary)

                guard let messageUserId = message.fromId else {
                    return
                }

                self.fetchUser(withId: messageUserId)

                self.messages.append(message)

                self.attemptReloadOfCollection()

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //scroll to the last index
                   // let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.messages.count - 1, section: 0)
                   // self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

The function is getting called all of its times before the first call to database is made. So if I were to put a print(uid) above the Firebase call, it would print all uids before it makes a call to the database.

Database Structure for users:
[[image: "database structure users"]]

Database Structure for groups:
[[image: "database structure groups"]]

Comment: Please show the structure of your Firebase db

Comment: From where you are calling this method? can you please show that part of code?

Comment: The reference and everything is fine. Instead of going to the uid as it is passed in, it waits until the function has been called the total number of times it will be called, then makes the calls to the database. This doesn't allow it to make a call to the proper reference (I think)

Comment: Firebase DB is Asynchronous, Are you using any Sorting Method while you retrieve all the data from the Snapshot And Before Populating your collectionView ? According to me You are getting Data correct way as Not able to find any mistake in code , Can you share the codeFile to check The runtime Output ?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Done

Comment: @iOSGeek What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Are you providing timestamp Values When Message is being sent from one UID to Any chat Screen , As you may need A parameter to Sort the data , best one I feel is TimeStamp Value , If you are using it just get all the data in a Dictionary then Sort it with According to timestamp Values

Comment: @iOSGeek The messages are in the proper order, it is the users that aren't being appended to the array in the proper order. The uid comes in correctly, but then the Firebase call does not correspond to the uids being passed in. It uses the first uid passed, and calls that uid equal to the number of messages that user has in the group, then does that for the following users. So if the first person to post a message is Sue and she has posted 7 total messages, the first 7 messages show Sue as the sender regardless of who sends it

Comment: @iOSGeek So If I were to put a print(uid) statement immediately above the Firebase database call and another on the line following the FIRDatabase.database().... line, the first print(uid) statement would be called for the total number of messages and it would print the proper uid corresponding to the message. However, the print(uid) statement following the FIRDatabae... line would print the first person's uid a bunch of times, then the next users uid a bunch of times, etc

Comment: Sorry for late reply, is your problem solved or not?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 It is still not working. It seems to be automatically sorting the query in order of the user's posting (first user to post, then second user, etc). However, I don't want this to happen (nor am I telling it to happen) because then the user is not associated with the proper message

Comment: so you want the user at the same index in users array as the message is in messages array, right?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Exactly. And that is how it is passed into the function. However the Firebase call seems to be reordering it for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use completion handler to get the `user` back from the `fetchUser` method, then make a dictionary to put the `message` and `user` together.So you can do something like this:

```
private func fetchUser(withMessage message: Message, completionHandler: @escaping (User, Message) -> ()) {

        guard let messageUserId = message.fromId else {
                    return
        }    

       FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(messageUserId ).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let user = User()
            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageURL"] as? String
            //self.users.append(user)
            completionHandler(user, message)
            self.attemptReloadOfCollection()
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Then replace

```
self.fetchUser(withId: messageUserId)
```

with

```
self.fetchUser(withMessage: message) { user, message in

                 var dict = [String: Any]()
                 dict["user"] = user
                 dict["message"] = message
                 self.finalArr.append(dict)
                 print(self.finalArr) // to see if we have the right output


}
```

Comment: @connorvo what is the output of `print(self.finalArr)` array?

Comment: The users are now associated with the proper message, but they are appended to the array in the wrong order (still appending all of the first user to post's messages first followed by the second user to post and so on). I guess I could try to then order the array by message time?

Comment: @connorvo if your requirement is to have the latest messages then yes you can sort the array according to timestamps